# python: argparse throwing value error when combining positional and optional argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, argparse

I'm trying to use the argparse library in python to read in optional and required arguments. So far I'm doing this:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Cleanup Script for Folder')

parser.add_argument('PATH_TO_WORKDIR_ROOT',
                    type=str,
                    dest='PATH_TO_WORKDIR_ROOT',
                    action='store',
                    help='(absolute or) relative path to directory \n   to work on, e.g. "..\MyFolder\\"')
parser.add_argument('--PATH_TO_BACKUP_ROOT',
                    type=str,
                    dest='PATH_TO_BACKUP_ROOT',
                    action='store',
                    help='(absolute or) relative path to Backup-Directory \n   default is ".\BACKUP\"')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Now I'm testing my code and it gives me a value-error that I don't understand:

```
$ python argparsetest.py --help
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "argparsetest.py", line 5, in <module>
    parser.add_argument('PATH_TO_WORKDIR_ROOT', type=str, dest='PATH_TO_WORKDIR_ ROOT', action='store', help='(absolute or)
relative path to directory \n   to wo rk on, e.g. "..\MyFolder\\"')  
File "C:\Program
Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.3.0.1715.win-x86_
64\lib\argparse.py", line 1262, in add_argument
    raise ValueError('dest supplied twice for positional argument') ValueError: dest supplied twice for positional argument
```

There's only one positional argument, isn't there and the destinations are different. I don't really understand the hassle.

Comment: Try adding `--` to `PATH_TO_WORKDIR_ROOT` like `--PATH_TO_WORKDIR_ROOT`

Comment: The error is entirely within the 1st `add_argument` method.  The first string is the `dest`, and you aren't allowed to define it again with the keyword parameter.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#dest

Answer (score 27):

Look at the following code in **argparse.py**:

```
# =======================
# Adding argument actions
# =======================
def add_argument(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    add_argument(dest, ..., name=value, ...)
    add_argument(option_string, option_string, ..., name=value, ...)
    """

    # if no positional args are supplied or only one is supplied and
    # it doesn't look like an option string, parse a positional
    # argument
    chars = self.prefix_chars
    if not args or len(args) == 1 and args[0][0] not in chars:
        if args and 'dest' in kwargs:
            raise ValueError('dest supplied twice for positional argument')
        kwargs = self._get_positional_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
```

Since you did not precede `--` to PATH_TO_WORKDIR_ROOT it thinks that the first argument is `dest` therefore raising the Error when you supply `dest` again as a named argument.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that helped!

Answer (score 1):

```
parser.add_argument('PATH_TO_WORKDIR_ROOT',
                type=str,
                action='store',
                help='(absolute or) relative path to directory \n   to work on, e.g. "..\MyFolder\\"')
```

Remove dest from the first `add_argument` call